# Passing string parameters to linked Oracle Server procedures from SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, linked-server

I have an Oracle procedure called `P_CREATE_USER`. It takes a single `varchar2` parameter:

```
create or replace PROCEDURE 
P_CREATE_USER (P_USERID varchar2)
...
```

I can run this from Oracle as `EXEC P_CREATE_USER('MyUserId')`

We have the Oracle server linked to our SQL Server.

I've tried:

```
EXECUTE('P_CREATE_USER(''MyUserId'')') AT ORACLE_SERVER
```

For my trouble, I get:

> OLE DB provider "OraOLEDB.Oracle" for linked server "ORACLE_SERVER" returned message "ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement".
>   Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 1
>   Could not execute statement on remote server 'ORACLE_SERVER'.

I have tried a number of variants, using a space between `P_CREATE_USER` and the parameter instead of parenthesis. I've tried using `@P_USERID=''MyUserId''`. I have no problem running parameterless procedures this way, but I can't see to figure out how to pass a string...

**Update:** The UserId used for the linked server has permissions to run this procedure and can run it directly from Oracle. This is not a permissions issue. As best I can tell, the parameter is the only thing causing a problem.

Comment: Does the DB link on oracle has the grant permissions to execute this procedure?

Comment: Also, see if it helps you: http://www.dba-oracle.com/sf_ora_00900_invalid_sql_statement.htm

Comment: @JorgeCampos Yes, the userid used for the linked server has the necessary permissions.

Comment: So, it must be something related with the double quotes as mentioned on the link I provided you. Just to test. Create a procedure on oracle like this: `create or replace procedure P_CREATE_USER_test as puserid varchar2(30):='MyUserId'; begin P_CREATE_USER(puserid); end;` and call it from ms sql and see what happens.

Comment: @JorgeCampos I'm unsure what this is testing. As I already said in my post, I have no problem calling parameterless procedures. If this is merely to test whether or not I can call a parameterless procedure, I can.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution required checking the `Dynamic Parameters` property in the OraOLEDB.Oracle driver in SQL Server (Server Objects/Linked Servers/Providers/OraOLEDB.Oracle).

Then, to call the procedure, I had to do the following:

```
DECLARE @userid varchar(50)
SET @userid = 'MyUserId'
EXECUTE ('BEGIN P_CREATE_USER(?); END;', @userid) AT ORACLE_SERVER
```

Comment: You should mark this as the answer. FWIW, I've also been able to call Oracle procedures using OUTPUT parameters.  For instance, `DECLARE @ReturnMessage varchar(255); EXECUTE ('BEGIN ORACLE_PROC(?);END;',@ReturnMessage OUTPUT) AT ORACLE_SERVER; PRINT @ReturnMessage`