# Get Dates to Variables from Oracle SQL in SQL Server using Linked Server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

I am trying to pass dates to the Sql Server Stored Procedure where i will get the dates from Oracle Database using Linked Server.
This is the first time i am working on Sql Server Procedure, Could some one please help me how to get the dates  from @Datesql to variables(@BeginDate, @EndDate) to further pass it to stored procedure ?

As this query results in only 1 row, Is it possible to capture the Print results in variables?

When i do Print i was getting the dates in Sql Server.

Any help would be appreciated.
Thanks.

```
USE [dev]
GO

DECLARE @Datesql varchar(1000);
DECLARE @sysdate varchar(30) = Convert(varchar(20),GETDATE(),101);
DECLARE @BeginDate nvarchar(30);
DECLARE @EndDate nvarchar(30);

set @Datesql='SELECT TO_CHAR(A.WW_WEEK_END_DT-6,''YYYY-MM-DD''),TO_CHAR(A.WW_WEEK_END_DT,''YYYY-MM-DD'')  FROM XX_PUNCH_TBL'

print @Datesql
execute(@Datesql) at orclhrdev

--SET @BeginDate='2014-12-01'
--SET @EndDate='2014-12-01'

DECLARE @return_value_Punch int

EXEC    @return_value_Punch = [dbo].[XX_PUNCH] @BeginDate,@EndDate

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value_Punch

GO
```

Answer (score 0):

**If** you want to copy some values returned by that `exec(...) at linkedserver` into `@BeginDate`, `@EndDate` variables then you could use a tables variable plus `SELECT @variabile = Column ... FROM @table_variable` thus:

```
DECLARE @ResultsFromOrclHRDev TABLE (
    BeginDate VARCHAR(10), -- You could try also DATE / DATETIME 
    EndDate VARCHAR(10)
);

INSERT @ResultsFromOrclHRDeb (BeginDate, EndDate)
EXECUTE(@Datesql) AT orclhrdev;

SELECT @BeginDate = x.BeginDate, @EndDate = x.EndDate
FROM @ResultsFromOrclHRDeb x
-- WHERE conditions ?
```

Note: To store date / time values I would use [the proper data type](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx): DATE, DATETIME,  SMALLDATETIME, [etc.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff848733.aspx) and not `NVARCHAR(30)`.

Also, you could try using `OUTPUT` parameters with this linked server thus (solution wasn't tested):

```
set @Datesql='SELECT TO_CHAR(A.WW_WEEK_END_DT-6,''YYYY-MM-DD'')  INTO ?,TO_CHAR(A.WW_WEEK_END_DT,''YYYY-MM-DD'') INTO ? FROM XX_PUNCH_TBL'

-- print @Datesql
execute(@Datesql, @BeginDate OUTPUT, @EndDate OUTPUT) at orclhrdev

-- select @BeginDate AS BD, @EndDate AS END
```

Note: Please see selected solution for this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077370/passing-string-parameters-to-linked-oracle-server-procedures-from-sql-server).