# Linked Server Stored Procedure call from MSSQL > ORACLE

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures, linked-server

I am trying to make an SP call from MSSQL to ORACLE, they are both setup in a linked server environment successfully, the only issue im having is creating the SQL SP call to Oracle;

Below is the procedure I am trying to reproduce in SQL as the SP call;

```
SET TIMING ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON
DECLARE 
  AVEMAIL VARCHAR2(255);
  ANCDPXID NUMBER;
  AVCDPURN VARCHAR2(12);

BEGIN 
  AVEMAIL := 'a@b.com';
  ANCDPXID := NULL;
  AVCDPURN := NULL;

  STP_FAC_PERSON ( AVEMAIL, ANCDPXID, AVCDPURN );

  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('ANCDPXID = ' || TO_CHAR(ANCDPXID));
  DBMS_OUTPUT.Put_Line('AVCDPURN = ' || AVCDPURN);

END;
```

I have attempted many times with examples below, but all not working;

```
SELECT * FROM OPENQUERY(FACUAT, '{Call FACUAT.CDBWEB.TACOMCDB.STP_FAC_PERSON( ''test@test.com'','''',''''}' )

EXEC ('CALL TACOMCDB.STP_FAC_PERSON(''test@test.com'','''','''')') at FACUAT

EXEC FACUAT.CDBWEB.TACOMCDB.STP_FAC_PERSON
```

Please advise
Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

just to update, below is the working query, plus i resintalled the 32-bit Oracle driver;

```
EXECUTE('Call STP_CAF_PERSON(?,?,?)', @AVEMAIL OUTPUT, @ANCDPXID OUTPUT, @AVCDPURN OUTPUT) AT [CAFUAT]
```

Answer (score 1):

If I am not wrong OPENQUERY won't work when used to call Oracle store procedures.
 Please try -

```
DECLARE @param_in_1 VARCHAR(255);
DECLARE @param_out_1 INT;
DECLARE @param_out_2 VARCHAR(12);
SET @param_in_1 = 'test@test.com';
EXECUTE ('BEGIN TACOMCDB.STP_FAC_PERSON(?,?,?); END;', @param_in_1,@param_out_1 OUTPUT, @param_out_2 OUTPUT) AT FACUAT;
SELECT @param_out_1,@param_out_2;
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, seems like its almost there, however i also get an error message;

Comment: (1 row(s) affected)
    Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 6
    Could not execute statement on remote server 'FACUAT'.

Comment: please check the below link - 
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20077370/passing-string-parameters-to-linked-oracle-server-procedures-from-sql-server)

Comment: Thanks for your help so far Abhishek, to trying to make things clearer I have posted the query with some modifications to my query here;
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32075667/passing-stored-procedure-from-mssql-to-oracle-linked-server

Comment: Thanks for your kind words, would have been glad if that helped you. Anyways could you please provide the linked server (FACUAT) details.

Comment: Hi Abhishek, its an Oracle 11g server, and im connecting from a SQL 2005 server. Please let me know if you require further info?

Comment: The SP seems to fall over at the Execute stage, all other parts of the SP seem fine?     
   `EXECUTE ('BEGIN TACOMCDB.STP_FAC_PERSON(?,?,?); END;', @param_in_1,@param_out_1 OUTPUT, @param_out_2 OUTPUT) AT FACUAT;`

Comment: _(1 row(s) affected) Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 11 Could not execute statement on remote server 'FACUAT'_

Comment: The script used to create the linked server would be helpful, also did you do any sanity check if the linked server was actually working by doing a select maybe to some random table under CDBWEB user -  SELECT *
FROM OPENQUERY([FACUAT], 'SELECT TABLE_NAME, OWNER FROM ALL_TABLES') 
or maybe calling a different SP all together.
Do check this link might be helpful - [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/307636/how-do-you-setup-a-linked-server-to-an-oracle-database-on-sql-2000-2005)

Comment: It was created with a TNS connection, i have also made successful select calls to the server.