# Passing Stored Procedure from SQL Server to ORACLE linked server

Tags: sql-server, oracle, stored-procedures

I'm trying to pass the following SQL query as a linked server stored procedure, but I get an error, please advise, thanks in advance!

> Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 17
>   Could not execute statement on remote server 'CAFUAT'.

Explanations:

- CAFUAT = Oracle Linked server
- CDBWEB = User
- STP_CAF_PERSON = stored procedure

Code:

```
DECLARE @AVEMAIL VARCHAR(255) 
DECLARE @ANCDPXID NUMERIC
DECLARE @AVCDPURN VARCHAR(12) 

SELECT @AVEMAIL  = 'a@b.com' 
SELECT @ANCDPXID  = null 
SELECT @AVCDPURN  = null 

EXECUTE ('BEGIN CAFUAT.CDBWEB.STP_CAF_PERSON(?,?,?,?); END;', @AVEMAIL,@ANCDPXID,@AVCDPURN) AT CAFUAT

DECLARE @PrintVariable VARCHAR (4000)

SELECT @PrintVariable =  'ANCDPXID ='  +  CONVERT(VARCHAR(23), @ANCDPXID) 
PRINT @PrintVariable

SELECT @PrintVariable =  'AVCDPURN ='  +  ISNULL(CAST(@AVCDPURN AS VARCHAR(8000)), '' ) 
PRINT @PrintVariable
```

Comment: Ha. That unformatted `GO` at the end of your post makes it sound like you're ordering us to get to work :)

Comment: Just a thought, you've got four question marks in your statement, but only 3 parameters listed afterwards; are you missing a parameter? Also, is "CDBWEB" the schema user or a package name?

Comment: Hi Boneist, you are correct, i have removed the extra question mark.
CDBWEB is the user which has privileges to execute the SP on the linked ORACLE server.

Comment: However, its still showing the same error message:

Comment: AVCDPURN =
Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 16
Could not execute statement on remote server 'CAFUAT'.

Comment: Thanks for the tidy up on my post marc_s!

Comment: The SP is falling over at the execution stage  
`EXECUTE ('BEGIN CAFUAT.CDBWEB.STP_CAF_PERSON(?,?,?); END;', @AVEMAIL,@ANCDPXID,@AVCDPURN) AT CAFUAT`   

  _(1 row(s) affected)
Msg 7215, Level 17, State 1, Line 11
Could not execute statement on remote server 'CAFUAT'._

Answer (score 1, accepted):

just to update, below is the working query, plus i resintalled the 32-bit Oracle driver;

```
EXECUTE('Call STP_CAF_PERSON(?,?,?)', @AVEMAIL OUTPUT, @ANCDPXID OUTPUT, @AVCDPURN OUTPUT) AT [CAFUAT]
```